# HTML select display value attribute but retain option text without using jQuery

Tags: html, css, reactjs, select

I'm working on creating a select form, but I'm trying to display only flag when language is selected, however when going through options I want to display flag and language label, sort of like this:

[image]

[image]

Example of `language` I'm mapping bellow

```
flag: ""
key: "es"
label: "Español"
locale: "es_ES"
```

My current form:

```
<form >
  <select value={lang} onChange={e => setLang(e.target.value)}>
    {availableLanguages.map(language => {
      return (
        <option key={language.key} value={language.key}>
          {language.flag}{language.label}
        </option>
      )
    }
    )}
  </select>
</form>
```

I know I need to change my `select` but I haven't found a solution to achieve this without jQuery